# How call SQL function in java? (call without 'select')

Tags: java, sql, function, postgresql

I have my SQL function (database PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adduser(idTopic integer, name character varying, email character varying)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE checkName BOOLEAN;
    BEGIN

INSERT INTO Users (idTopic, name, email)
    VALUES (idTopic, name, email);

select (users.name=$2) into checkName from users where users.email = $3;

 return checkName;

    END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

And I can call this function from java:

```
@Override
  public void add(User user) {

  String queryAdd = "select adduser(" + user.getTopic().getId() + ",'" + user.getName() + "','" + user.getEmail() + "')";

        Query query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryAdd);
        query.list();

  }
```

But I need to have query without word 'select', I need "adduser(idTopic, name, email)", How can I to do it?

Comment: This is fairly [well documented](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/callproc.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider though that link is to a very old version of the docs, in particular *"PostgreSQL™ does not support functions that have output parameters"* hasn't been accurate for ages.

Comment: I need call my SQL function from java-code by hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
do $$ begin perform adduser(idTopic, name, email); end; $$
```

Although I don't know much about java interfaces anymore, the above gives you a call to the function without using the word 'select'.

-g